# nagios_host type object duplication when apply puppet manifest

Tags: puppet, nagios

I'm trying to apply a single manifest containing several nagios hosts and getting an error: "can not create alias xxxxx object already exists".
  Now, in nagios, you can have several hosts with the same alias.

Reading the nagios_type documentation, it seems as though apart from the alias parameter or attribute, a puppet metaparameter can also be defined in a give nagios_host resource.

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/types/nagios_host.html

The feeling I get is that puppet is understanding "alias" as a metaparameter instead of the nagios_host attribute. If that makes sense, is there a way to tell puppet which of the two it is.

Here's the manifest in question:

```
nagios_host { 'host1':
  ensure         => 'present',
  address        => 'ip',
  alias          => 'example',
  contact_groups => 'noc',
  hostgroups     => 'hostgroup',
  icon_image     => 'school.gif',
  icon_image_alt => 'School',
  parents        => 'parent',
  target         => '/etc/nagios/nagios_host.cfg',
  use            => 'schools-router',
}

nagios_host { 'host2':
  ensure         => 'present',
  address        => 'ip',
  alias          => 'example',
  contact_groups => 'noc',
  hostgroups     => 'hostgroup',
  icon_image     => 'school.gif',
  icon_image_alt => 'School',
  parents        => 'parent',
  target         => '/etc/nagios/nagios_host.cfg',
  use            => 'schools-router',
}
```

Also, I have tried different version of puppet agent to rule out it had to do with that.

Comment: The error you are getting is very likely for the resource name alias (e.g. the `path` on a `file` resource) being used more than once and not the alias resource attribute for the `nagios_host` resource. If you feel completely certain that you are not in error of multiple declarations, then I would recommend filing an issue on their JIRA.

Comment: Thanks for articulating it acurately Matt. Actually, there's this thread (https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/3507) where they where requesting to name it nagios_alias. Apparently they have not changed it. I'll keep exploring.

Comment: Yes, parameters named `alias` are special to Puppet.  You have run across a flaw in the `Nagios_host` type -- apparently a very old one.  I suspect that the issue has been lost, as I do not find it in [Puppet's current issue tracker](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com), only in the old one.  I'd encourage you to file a new ticket referencing the original issue, which was, after all, accepted and never closed.

Comment: I do not have a workaround to suggest, I'm afraid, other than locally fixing the type yourself.  I suspect that the absence of a workaround -- if indeed I'm not overlooking something -- may be a key factor in this issue being fixed after being in the codebase for so long.

Comment: @igarcia I can take a look at the source code at some point to see how easy it would be to fix this. I regularly contribute code to Puppet, so I keep an up to date fork around as well as being familiar with their arduous process of contributing.

Comment: Thanks John & Matt. Sure I'll open a new one in the current issue tracker. Just to pinpoint what was going on, I changed all appearances of "alias" for "nagios_alias" in external/nagios/base.rb, and the resources are created indeed. If only I knew a little more ruby to fix it. However I'm sure a developer will fix it in a blink of an eye :)

Comment: @igarica Just ping me here with the JIRA URL and I will pick it up in case Kylo or David gives it a pass on the reassignment.

Comment: there you go. https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-6677. I saw two users with your name @MattSchuchard, so I assigned it to Kylo. Cheers again!

Comment: @igarcia It is supposed to be auto-assigned based on the criteria filled out, and David may have token over the agent issue assignment from Kylo at this point, but that can all be easily fixed. I edited your ticket some and will look at it tomorrow.